# Error using Merge Replication to SQL Compact 3.5

Tags: .net, sql-server, sql-server-ce

We are getting the following error when syncing with sql server (2005 SP3):

Initializing SQL Server Reconciler has failed. Try again.; The merge process could not connect to the message file from Subscriber '{F238C7BC-E13B-40E4-99F2-F11A203BD65A}:W:\http_content\Secure\SECURE_PROD\data_merge\30.18F5D9B4BCC7_B1415013-9FB7-424A-AB45-643A0D4A6320.IN'. Check to ensure that the server is running.; The subscription to publication 'COREPublication' could not be verified. Ensure that all Merge Agent command line parameters are specified correctly and that the subscription is correctly configured. If the Publisher no longer has information about this subscription, drop and recreate the subscription.

As far as I can work out, everything is fine on the sql server side. I've done all the checks mentioned in the error message.

Can anyone tell me what this error message actually means? Is it unable to read the shapshot file off the server? (this is my guess currently).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is caused when you have SQL Compact 3.5 SP1 installed, and talking to a pre-SP1 server. Something changed in the service pack that stops it working.

Uninstalling the service pack works, so this is our current workaround until the service pack is approved and installed in production (i.e. the server).

I cannot test at this time, but I assume that SP1 talking to a SP1 server works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am using both 3.5 SP1 client and 3.5 SP1 server and both works perfectly well.
The version of both components is 3.5.5692.0.
The referenced client assembly shall be 3.5.1.0 in the .NET client solution (running on CE).

I got the same error (and it did not make any sense) but simply restarting the server (in my case Windows 2003 Server) made the error go away. It may have to do with some previous version component still running after installation.

You can verify that you have 3.5 SP1 running by visiting its URL, e.g.
http://x.x.x.x/dir_of_dll/sqlcesa35.dll?diag

Under "SQL Server Compact Modules Test", it should say "sqlcesa35.dll" Version 3.5.5692.0, and all tests should pass with status SUCCESS.

Comment: yes, the problem is that if you have a SP1 client, and a NON-SP1 server, you get the above error all the time.